# Django command: how to schedule properly on Windows Server

Tags: python, django, windows, server, scheduling

coming from Linux I have to build a Django application on Windows Server.

Everything works fine, but I have a Django command that needs to be run every hour.

In Linux I would create a cronjob.

I wrote a batch file that activates the virtual env and runs the django command, scheduled it with windows, but the command jobs fails, despite task scheduler says it executed properly.
What is simple on Linux on Windows it seems to be rocket science...

I feel that task scheduler / batch file approach isn't the right way to do that.

Is there a more pythonesque way to run a django command on windows server every hour?

thanx in advance,

Jan

Comment: Scheduled tasks starts as a different user (SYSTEM). Python and Django should be available to every Windows user.

Answer (score 1):

coming back late, but I solved it with a django custom command:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

strophi